# Possibility to discuss a review

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, review, rejected-edits

Just a suggestion here. Here is an accepted answer which is inaccurate: [Get album artwork from ID3 tag/Convert function from Java to Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607401/get-album-artwork-from-id3-tag-convert-function-from-java-to-objective-c/6699370#6699370)

The current snippet of code isn't working so I tried to edit it.

Unfortunately, the reviewers rejected my edit saying it was too far from the current answer. But the fact is, the current answer is wrong, can't work, and I have no way to say it to my reviewers.

I'd like to be able to discuss a review rejection, to be able to talk to my reviewers. That's kind of frustrating :)

Comment: @Mysticial: I think you miss the point, and that alone does not help anyone trying to get the code to work. Martin however I don't agree this is a necessary utility, to be able to discuss your reviewed edit. You have comments and can post new answers.

Comment: You can't force anyone to change their answer. If it's wrong or not helpful, then downvote it and leave a comment.

Comment: @Mysticial: The author of the post even said the code doesn't work, and in the comments people mentioned it did work with some modification. Sorry but your first comment just seemed dismissive, perhaps it was not meant to be.

Comment: So Martin, welcome to meta but I fully [disagree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) with this request. You are able to put a message in the revision history, that is enough. Opening up a discussion/chat for this would be a feature I would not want and don't think we need.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Fine, I was a bit too blunt in my first comment. I was basically saying that the proper way to deal with posts that you don't agree with is to downvote it. If he can't edit it into a form that he agrees with, then the only reasonable option is to either leave it be or downvote.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that reviewers are not always subject matter experts for the suggested edits they review, so when they see code edits, the default response is to reject them. We've had a few instances where a correct answer was edited into something wrong due to a bad suggested edit. That makes us a little gunshy when it comes to changes like this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your answer is correct, post it as a new answer. Don't try to edit someone else's answer to make it into something else. The code you posted in the answer looks vastly different than his original code... As well, rather than just stating "this is their answer but working" try explaining **what you changed and why it works now**.

Editing another user's code should be reserved for minor modifications such as spelling errors or very small instances of wrong class names used, etc where it is blatantly obvious that they intended it to be that way. Completely rewriting their code is never an acceptable use of editing.

Comment: By posting the correct answer yourself, you'll also be rewarded with reputation. Much more than if your edit were approved, at least.

Answer (score 9):

I would say the correct way of handling this is by downvoting the answer and add your own answer. I see you already have left a comment stating it is probably wrong.

Not much else you can / should do.

Answer (score 3):

By introducing this feature you're basically adding more work for the reviewers, instead of a simple veto process (involving more than one person btw) it might turn into an entire discussion of "but I know I'm right" and "I disagree". Add voting to it and you have yourself another meta site :)

Work with the system, not against it.